# Determining string length in Node JS when string may be null

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, if-statement, null

I'm trying to learn Node and have the function:

```
this.logMeIn = function(username,stream) {
  if (username === null || username.length() < 1) {
    stream.write("Invalid username, please try again:\n\r");
    return false;
  } else {
  ....etc
```

and I'm passing it

```
if (!client.loggedIn) {
  if (client.logMeIn(String(data.match(/\S+/)),stream)) {
```

I've tried both == and ===, but I'm still getting errors as the username is not detecting that it is null, and username.length() fails on:

```
if (username === null || username.length() < 1) {
                                  ^
TypeError: Property 'length' of object null is not a function
```

I'm sure that Node won't evaluate the second part of the || in the if statement when the first part is true - but I fail to understand why the first part of the if statement is evaluating to false when username is a null object.  Can someone help me understand what I've done wrong?

Comment: Delete this comment and add it under my answer, we will continue chatting under my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're passing `String(data.match(/\S+/))` as `username` argument, so when `data.match(/\S+/)` is `null`, you get `"null"` not `null` for `username`, as:

```
String(null) === "null"
```

So you need to change your condition:

```
if( username === null || username === "null" || username.length < 1 )
```

Comment: If he was getting the string `"null"`, then he wouldn't be getting an error on `"null".length"` - it would be 4.

Comment: @jmar777 It doesn't metter in this case, 'cause `username === "null"` is `true` in that case, and `if`'s body will be executed.

Comment: Right, but the existing code is comparing to `null`, not `"null"` - so the error when calling `.length` is separate. That was a good catch on the funky `String(data.match())` thing though.

Comment: @jmar777 So OP's problem was comparing to `null`,but not to `'null'`. Also I have updated my condition.

Comment: I don't think that was the case.  The OP's original error was `TypeError: Property 'length' of object null is not a function`. If `username` at that point was actually a string containing `"null"`, then that error would not happen, as `username.length` would return `4`, rather than throw an error.

Comment: Ok, so because I was converting it to String() before passing it, I was making it "null", and .length() is wrong... What I really was wanting to do is pass in data.match() results and then convert to String() only when I knew it was a valid response. Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 11):

`length` is an attribute, not a function. Try `username.length`

Comment: Either `username` is no string then or you are doing something wrong!

Comment: I was wrong - length is properly evaluating to the length of the passed string. However, this doesn't solve the original problem of how do I know if I'm passed a null object?  null.length doesn't evaluate?!

Answer (score 1):

If you require a non-empty string, you can do a simple "truthy" check that will work for `null`, `undefined`, `''`, etc:

```
if (username) { ... }
```

With that approach, you don't even need the `.length` check.  Also, `length` is a property, not a method.

---

Edit: You have some funkiness going on. I think you need to start with how you're passing in your username - I don't think that your `String(data.match(/\S+/))` logic is behaving the way that you're expecting it to (credit to @Engineer for spotting this).

Your match expression is going to return one or two types of values: `null` or an `Array`.  In the case that it's null, as @Engineer pointed out, you end up passing in `"null"` as a string, which should resultantly pass your username check later on.  You should consider revising this to:

```
if (!client.loggedIn) {
    var matches = data.match(/\S+/);
    if (client.logMeIn(matches ? matches[0] : '',stream)) {
```

Regarding `.length` being equal to `1` in all cases - that doesn't honestly make a lot of sense. I would recommend adding a lot of `console.log()` statements to try and figure out what's going on.

Comment: This fixes the problem with the first part of the evaluation (thanks), but now username.length always evaluates to 1, no matter how long the data is coming in.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hrm, actually - this isn't working either... if (username) is evaluating to true whether it's null or not...

Comment: I eventually want the length check to be more...it's a placeholder for more complex logic.

Comment: What was happening in the first run throughs is I was thinking .match was returning a string - it was returning an array, as you mention - which was evaluating to length[1] (since I was entering one name).  Further logic was applied and I got lost in all the changes.  All is sorted out now that I understand that String(null) gives you "null" and data.match() gives you an array.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try

if( username === null || username.toString().length < 1 )

I used if( username === null || username.length < 1 ) and it failed at length check.